# Disable network adapter without WMI

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I found a few answers on google describing how to disable the network adapter "Local Area Connection" on Windows 7 and 8 by using WMI. I also found a method by using shell but it only works with Windows XP. I would like to know if its possible to disable adapters without using WMI with C# or VB.NET code on Win7 and Win8..

Comment: WMI is _the_ way to do many similar tasks, so even though I'm no big fan of WMI it might be the most supported and most reliable way of doing what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe","/c netsh interface set interface 'Local Area Connection' DISABLED");
```