# How to close all connections to internet?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I've got a basic .NET application I've written for a public library which simply enables and disables internet access. It does this by toggling the firewall, and leverages UAC to prompt for administrator credentials.

It works well, however it doesn't close existing connections. Facebook Messenger for examples holds a connection open and continues working long after the firewall has been enabled and block all internet access.

Ideally, I want to close all connections to outside the local subnet. If that's not possible, closing all connections over port 80/443 would also work. I want to avoid having to kill the actual processes that have these connections open, and would rather just kill the connections themselves.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not specifically what you want You could probably brute force the *Network Adapter*. When re-enabled it would allow your firewall rules to kick in

Basically, no Adapter not internet

---

[Disable network adapter without WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099035/disable-network-adapter-without-wmi)

**Netsh**

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe","/c netsh interface set interface 'Local Area Connection' DISABLED")
```

---

[Disable/enable network adapter using WMI](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Disableenable-network-8112f642/sourcecode?fileId=84557&pathId=2134893072)

**Get network adpaters**

```
public static List<NetworkAdapter> GetAllNetworkAdapter()
{
   List<NetworkAdapter> allNetworkAdapter = new List<NetworkAdapter>();

   // Manufacturer <> 'Microsoft'to get all none virtual devices. 
   // Because the AdapterType property will be null if the NetworkAdapter is  
   // disabled, so we do not use NetworkAdapter = 'Ethernet 802.3' or  
   // NetworkAdapter = 'Wireless’ 
   string strWQuery = "SELECT DeviceID, ProductName, "
                        + "NetEnabled, NetConnectionStatus "
                        + "FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter "
                        + "WHERE Manufacturer <> 'Microsoft'";

   ManagementObjectCollection networkAdapters = WMIOperation.WMIQuery(strWQuery);
   foreach (ManagementObject moNetworkAdapter in networkAdapters)
   {
      try
      {
         allNetworkAdapter.Add(new NetworkAdapter(
                                                   Convert.ToInt32(moNetworkAdapter["DeviceID"].ToString()),
                                                   moNetworkAdapter["ProductName"].ToString(),
                                                   (Convert.ToBoolean(moNetworkAdapter["NetEnabled"].ToString()))
                                                      ? (int)EnumNetEnabledStatus.Enabled
                                                      : (int)EnumNetEnabledStatus.Disabled,
                                                   Convert.ToInt32(moNetworkAdapter["NetConnectionStatus"].ToString()
                                                                  )));
      }
      catch (NullReferenceException)
      {
         // Ignore some other devices (like the bluetooth), that need user  
         // interaction to enable or disable. 
      }
   }

   return allNetworkAdapter;
}
```

**Enable Disable**

```
public int EnableOrDisableNetworkAdapter(string strOperation)
{
   int resultEnableDisableNetworkAdapter = (int)EnumEnableDisableResult.Unknow;
   ManagementObject crtNetworkAdapter = new ManagementObject();

   string strWQuery = string.Format("SELECT DeviceID, ProductName, "
                                    + "NetEnabled, NetConnectionStatus "
                                    + "FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter " + "WHERE DeviceID = {0}", DeviceId);

   try
   {
      ManagementObjectCollection networkAdapters =
         WMIOperation.WMIQuery(strWQuery);
      foreach (ManagementObject networkAdapter in networkAdapters)
      {
         crtNetworkAdapter = networkAdapter;
      }

      crtNetworkAdapter.InvokeMethod(strOperation, null);

      Thread.Sleep(500);
      while (GetNetEnabled() != ((strOperation.Trim() == "Enable")
                                    ? (int)EnumNetEnabledStatus.Enabled
                                    : (int)EnumNetEnabledStatus.Disabled))
      {
         Thread.Sleep(100);
      }

      resultEnableDisableNetworkAdapter =
         (int)EnumEnableDisableResult.Success;
   }
   catch (NullReferenceException)
   {
      // If there is a NullReferenceException, the result of the enable or  
      // disable network adapter operation will be fail 
      resultEnableDisableNetworkAdapter = (int)EnumEnableDisableResult.Fail;
   }

   crtNetworkAdapter.Dispose();

   return resultEnableDisableNetworkAdapter;
}
```